# Why does the strcpy() function produce unwanted outputs in the case of this program?

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list in C and this post refers to the part where I try to assign a variable in a structure a string value that the user inputs. The program compiles perfectly yet if I use strcpy() instead of strdup() then I get unwanted output.

The program compiles fine and gives no warnings or errors. If strdup() is used then the program works as intended but I'd like to know why it doesn't work when strcpy() is used instead. When passing in strings for the names, when the list is printed it will occasionally print null and then terminate or it will instead print "Name:Name:Name:Name:Nam" or other such unpredictable errors. Any other comments or criticisms would be appreciated as well as I am just starting to learn the language, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct addressBook {
    char *name;
    int age;
    char *phoneNumber;
    struct addressBook *next;
};

static struct addressBook *head = NULL;
static struct addressBook *current;
static struct addressBook *createNew;

//function prototypes
void addNode(void);
struct addressBook * createNode(void);
void printAddressBook(void);
void printStats(void);


int main(void)
{
    addNode();
    addNode();
    printAddressBook();
    addNode();
    addNode();
    printAddressBook();
}

struct addressBook * createNode(void)
{
    struct addressBook *newNode;
    newNode = (struct addressBook *) malloc(sizeof(struct addressBook));

if (newNode == NULL)
{
    puts("Memory error");
    exit(1);
}

printf("\nEnter persons name: ");
char name[20];
scanf("%s", name);
strcpy(newNode -> name, name); //produces unpredictable results
//newNode -> name = strdup(name);   Works fine with strdup

printf("Enter persons age: ");
scanf("%d", &newNode -> age);

printf("Enter persons phone number: ");
char phoneNumber[15];
scanf("%s", phoneNumber);
strcpy(newNode -> phoneNumber, phoneNumber); //produces unpredictable 
results
//newNode -> phoneNumber = strdup(phoneNumber);  Works fine with strdup

return(newNode);
}

void addNode(void)
{
    createNew = createNode();
    current = createNew;
    current -> next = head;
    head = current;
}

void printAddressBook(void)
{
    struct addressBook *temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\nAge: %d\nPhoneNumber: %s\n\n\n",
               temp -> name,
               temp -> age,
               temp -> phoneNumber);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}
```

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: OT:  when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  I.E. this: `newNode = (struct addressBook *) malloc(sizeof(struct addressBook));`  should be: `newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct addressBook));`

Comment: the posted code has a massive memory leak. Every memory allocation 'should' be matched with a call to 'free()` before the program exits.  I.E. to do write code that requires the OS to cleanup afterward

Comment: OT:  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions. 1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers: '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoid a possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 6):

When you define a pointer like `char *name;` it points to some random location as you haven't initialized it. It is illegal to write to the pointer and doing so will invoke Undefined Behavior.

`strcpy` basically writes the string to this random pointer location invoking UB.
`strdup` on the other hand, allocates the required memory dynamically for the string, copies the string to that location and then returns the start of the location. You can read/write to this memory location and hence, this is valid.